# Text in jetpack compose not showing text?

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, kotlin-flow

This class simply emit character after 1-sec delay

```
class MainViewModel: ViewModel() {
    var bouncingName = flow<Char> {
        val text="hemant"
        for (letter in text){
            delay(1000L)
            emit(letter)
        }
    }
}
```

This main class displays string after concatenating string display on the app

```
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    @SuppressLint("CoroutineCreationDuringComposition")
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            CompleteGuideKotlinFlowTheme {
                // A surface container using the 'background' color from the theme
                var letter by remember {
                    mutableStateOf(StringBuilder())
                }
                val viewModel = viewModel<MainViewModel>()
                //  var currentValue=viewModel.countDownValue.collectAsState(initial = 10)
                lifecycleScope.launch {
                    viewModel.bouncingName.collect {
                        letter.append(it)
                        Log.d("TAG", "Character in main $letter")
                    }
                }

                Box(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                    contentAlignment = Alignment.Center) {
                    Text(
                        text = letter.toString(),
                        fontSize = 30.sp
                    )
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But nothing is showing on the app.
I don't understand why?

Answer (score 1):

`StringBuilder` is mutable. When you append to it, Compose doesn't get notified and the recomposition doesn't happen. You should use immutable types with `MutableState` and update it using `MutableState`'s setter:

```
var letter by remember { mutableStateOf("") }
...
letter = letter + it
```

Comment: Using this code 'letter' display continues on screen. why?

Comment: @hemant you mean why it works? It uses immutable String instead of StringBuilder. When you update StringBuilder, Compose doesn't know about it because this is the same object. Read caution message here: https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/state#use-other-types-of-state-in-jetpack-compose